# Looping over a dict trying to extract data into a new data set give error name not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the python-noob question and I need some help on my home work issue im trying to loop through the input file and create a list with new key value names.

I have some data im reading in from a file:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2019-06-19T12:37:10.599Z",
      "name": "In"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2019-06-19T10:40:36.233Z",
      "name": "Out"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2019-06-19T06:25:21.473Z",
      "name": "In"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2019-06-04T08:12:23.795Z",
      "name": "Out"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2019-06-19T12:37:10.599Z",
      "name": "In"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2019-06-19T10:40:36.233Z",
      "name": "Out"
    }
  ]
}
```

I read this data in and then am trying to use the following code:

```
data = []
output_data = []

for item in full_data:
    if full_data.get('name') == 'In':
        li_time = sorted(full_data, key=lambda x: (x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), reverse=True).pop()
    if full_data.get('name') == 'In':
        fi_time = sorted(full_data, key=lambda x: (x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')).pop()
    if full_data.get('name') == 'Out':
        lo_time = sorted(full_data, key=lambda x: (x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), reverse=True).pop()
    data = {
        'id': full_data.get('id'),
        'first_in_time': fi_time,
        'last_in_time': li_time,
        'last_out_time': lo_time,
    }
    output_data.append(data)
```

My idea is to loop over the full_data and for each item use pop() to get the earliest 'In' time, the latest 'In' time and the latest 'Out' time for each id.

this would then give me an output_data of:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_in_time": "2019-06-19T06:25:21.473Z",
  "last_in_time": "2019-06-19T12:37:10.599Z",
  "last_out_time": "2019-06-19T10:40:36.233Z",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "first_in_time": "2019-06-19T12:37:10.599Z",
  "last_in_time": "2019-06-19T12:37:10.599Z",
  "last_out_time": "2019-06-19T10:40:36.233Z",
}
```

However it's both not picking up the `full_data.get('id')` and the names are not defined. when i try to define them the new data is just empty suggesting my loop is incorrect.

Comment: What is `full_data` defined as? Since you're iterating over it, the structure of that data will define how your loop performs.

Comment: is read in as a json file and in in the format in the first part above. its read in using:

with open('inputdata.json', 'r') as f:
    full_data = json.load(f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `full_data` contains the structure given above, iterating over it will give you the *key* from the first level:

```
for item in full_data:
  # item will be "1"
  ..
  # item will be "2"
```

This is not in line with your code as you probably want to iterate over the inner structure as well:

```
for k in full_data:
  # full_data[k] is however a list of in/out entries:
  for item in full_data[k]:
    # item is now {"id": "1", "date": ..., ... }
```

However there is probably a more readable way:

```
for k in full_data:
  # fetch the in and out values to a list with just the dates
  in_values = [x['date'] for x in full_data[k] if x['name'] == 'In']
  out_values = [x['date'] for x in full_data[k] if x['name'] == 'Out']

  output_data.append({
    "id": k,
    "first_in_time": min(in_values),
    "last_in_time": max(in_values),
    "last_out_time": max(out_values),
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i'm getting the error "ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence"

If i print(in_values) i get [] and []

Comment: It works as expected here. Make sure you're using the correct element (`full_data[k]`) inside the list comprehension that picks out the `date` values from alle lements. `print` the `full_data[k]` entry if necessary.

Comment: sorry I made an error typing - thank you. really appreciate the help. I think i was over complicating.